# Type guard function for the `[key, value]` entry

Tags: typescript

```js
const isNonNullable = <V>(value: V): value is NonNullable<V> =>
  value !== null && value !== undefined
```

How to make a generic type guard function like this one, but for the (`[key, value]`) entry?

I want to use it like this: `Object.entries(foobar).filter(isNonNullableEntry)`.

```js
const isNonNullableEntry = <T extends [K, V]>(entry: T): entry is [K, NonNullable<V>] =>
  entry[1] !== null && entry[1] !== undefined
```

The above is my incorrect attempt. How to make it right?

Comment: Explain how it's incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in some scope." [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

The `isNonNullableEntry` typeguard is parametrized by two arbitrary types `K` and `V`. The argument is a `[K, V]` tuple, so we use the typeguard to tell the compiler that it is guaranteed to be a `[K, NonNullable<V>]`, which is a subset of the `[K, V]`, so a valid case for using a typeguard.

```
const isNonNullableEntry = <K,V>(entry: [K, V]): entry is [K, NonNullable<V>] =>
  entry[1] !== null && entry[1] !== undefined
```

Comment: Ahhh so silly of me! Thank you

Comment: A question is not an answer. Please explain how your answer solves the problem of OP.

Comment: Didn't think about using two type parameters instead, thanks again. Solved!